# Why can't I get a property from instance of a class?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have Instance of a CollectionViewController defined with layout object.

```
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
     (1)let friendsController = FriendsController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: friendsController)
```

So in friendsController I've defined string property message.

```
class FriendsController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
fileprivate let cellId = "cellId"
var messages: [Message]?


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
   navigationItem.title = "Recent"
   collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    collectionView?.register(MessageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    setupData()

}
......
```

And yes i can get messages from (1)friendsController. But I defined instance of a FriendController class with empty initializer it defines, but i can't get messages property. I had suggestion that I got initiated parent class of UIViewColletionController class, but when saw additional information about FriendController class (initialed with empty initializer) it showed me that it is still 
       *class FriendsController : UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.* If someone could give a cue , it would help me a lot

Comment: It's unclear. "but i can't get messages property" Where did you attempt to do  so? Where is `messages` init?

Answer (score 0):

1. solution: You can create custom initializer in `FriendsController`

```
class FriendsController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
fileprivate let cellId = "cellId"
var messages: [Message]?

    init(collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout, and messages: [String]) {
        super.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        self.messages = messages
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "Recent"
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        collectionView?.register(MessageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        setupData()

    }
```

and then

```
    let messages: [Message] = []
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let friendsController = FriendsController(collectionViewLayout: layout, and: messages)
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: friendsController)
```

2. solution: just add only one line to first code

```
    let messages: [Message] = []
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let friendsController = FriendsController(collectionViewLayout: layout, and: messages)
    friendsController.messages = messages
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: friendsController)
```